# MPMediaPickerController - iOS7

Tags: ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

I developed test application on iOS 7 that pick the music from music library using MPMediaPickerController.
But when I present the media picker controller,it shows empty screen.
This is the code

```
(void) pickSong
{
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
    mediaPicker.prompt = NSLocalizedString(@"Select Your Favourite Song!", nil);
    [mediaPicker loadView];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - MPMediaPickerController delegate

(void) mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker2 didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.item.soundName = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    self.item.soundUrl = [[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] absoluteString];
}

(void) mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: nobody to help me? :(

Comment: Andrea, do you have any idea?

Comment: We have noticed the same behavior in our app when running on iPhone 5S and iOS 7.0.1. What kind of phone do you test with?

Comment: I've upgraded my iphone5 and tested with it.

Comment: Do you use xcode 5? When we try our old builds (built with xcode4) we have no problem. What version of xcode do you use?

Comment: yes, I am using xcode 5

Answer (score 4):

This is an iOS bug, but it only occurs when running a 32 bit build on a 64 bit (A7) device (Only iPhone 5S for now). To work around it, add a 64 bit architecture to your app. (Open build settings in xcode, and change Architecture from $ARCHS_STANDARD to $ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT.) You will then probably need to fix a number of compile, link and runtime issues. See Apple's 64-Bit Transition Guide.

Comment: nice try.. but this bug is happening on my iPod touch 5G device, which has an A5 chip which [is a 32 bit processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A5)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a bug in ios7 where it doesn't like to be presented inside a uinavigation controller - try presenting it directly from a view controller.

Comment: I've tried to present it inside of view controller.
[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
but it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: curious is your view controller inside a tabbarcontroller?

Comment: one more try :)- are you on an ios7 dev build from before the gold master?  They had the media picker complete disabled in some of the dev builds.

Comment: @EdFilowat mine is inside a tabbarcontroller.. why does that make a difference?

Comment: also @EdFilowat what's your reference on that?

Comment: @abbood -  Not sure,  apparently it was a bug-   it started working in subsequent updates to the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was a combination of two of the solutions presented here. First I had to convert my app to be 64-bit ready by changing Architectures to "standard... (including 64-bit)". Once I corrected all the warnings that caused, I had to change the `MPMediaPickerController` to be presented modally rather than on the navigation stack:

```
- (IBAction)didSelectMusicPicker:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

    picker.delegate                     = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");

    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:TRUE completion:NULL];
}
```

Of course, I also needed to change `mediaPicker:didPickMediaItems:` and `mediaPickerDidCancel:` to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. Once all that was fixed, the picker worked as expected on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5S running iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

a thought: is the presented screen *completely* empty, or are you getting the navigation bar at the bottom but with no tracks listed?  I've noticed that as of iOS 7 the picker now defaults to opening to the Playlist tab (it used to open to Albums, if I recall)… if you have no playlists on the device that would account for the empty screen…

Comment: Do you know of a way to change the default tab it opens?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the list of songs and select the songs. But I cannot dismiss the view controller on pressing "Done". I've tried PresentViewController since Modal controller is deprecated.

```
- (IBAction) showMediaPicker: (id) sender {

    picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

    picker.delegate                     = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
    [self.picker removeFromParentViewController];
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
   // [picker release];
}


// Responds to the user tapping Done after choosing music.
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {
    [self.picker removeFromParentViewController];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   //
    [self.delegate updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection: mediaItemCollection];
   // [self.mediaItemCollectionTable reloadData];

   // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];
}
```

I've tried RemovefromSuperview also, nothing seems to work. I'm testing this on an iPhone 6 simulator and an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.3.

Anyone???

Comment: your answer shouldn't be a question

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem before. But I found out just need to restart the device after upgrade. The music picker appear again.

Comment: I've tested with another device, but it's same.
and it happens same thing in emulator, too

Comment: Simulator never support MPMediaPickerController. You need to test it in device. Have you manually restart your device after upgrade to iOS7?

Comment: @PayneChu i've never seen anyone receive a vote up for a "restart" answer on stackoverflow.. _ever_