# MPMediaPickerController init works on device, but not in emulator (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

When I try to initialize an instance of MPMediaPickerController, I get this error:

> Could not request view controller: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 0.)"

Even just an alloc/init causes this to occur. Same result if I use initWithMediaTypes or any of the other init methods.

```
- (IBAction)pickSong:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] init];
}
```

Now the bizarre part: it works perfectly fine when I test it on an actual device! (The device is a gen 5 iPod Touch running iOS 7.0.4) Anyone have any idea why it might not be working on the emulator?

(I'm using the iPhone Retina Simulator running iOS 7.0.3.)

I don't believe that it is the same as [this user's issue with MPMediaPickerController in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933147/mpmediapickercontroller-ios7) because I confirmed that "Standard architectures (including 64-bit) ..." is the setting in my build settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792442/runtime-error-when-using-mpmediapickercontroller-in-ios-simulator

Comment: Thanks - this answers my question. It seems that the MPMediaPickerController just fails more gracefully in the simulator now than it did when that answer was posted!